# Unable to pass result of multi value selector to CONTAINS fucntion

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have an input xml. I want to evaluate a condition which uses a "contains" function to true or false. Here is the input xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <root>
    <order>
     <items>155</items>
    </order>
    <order>
     <items>30</items>
    </order>
    <order>
      <items>15</items>
    </order>
    <order>
    <items>5</items>
     </order>
    <order>
     <items>4</items>
     <items>7</items>
    </order>
   <order>
    <items>1</items>
     <items>3</items>
    </order>
    <order>
       null
   </order>
 </root>
```

I want to check weather a value of the items in the above xml contains 3 or 
  not. So I tried this code.

```
   %dw 1.0
    %output application/xml
   ---
        {
         Orders : payload.root.*order mapObject (
      doesItContains : $.*items contains "3" 
    )}
```

it  was giving me a error like this.

```
  Type mismatch for 'contains' operator
  found :null, :string
 required :array, :any or
required :string, :string or
 required
 :string, :regex
```

But when I have tried like this  this was working fine

```
           {
             Orders : payload.root.*order mapObject (
     doesItContains : $ mapObject (
         contains3: $ contains "3"
        ) 
       )
            }
```

It was giving the expected output.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>   
  <Orders>
  <doesItContains>
   <contains3>false</contains3>
  </doesItContains>
  <doesItContains>
     <contains3>true</contains3>
  </doesItContains>
  <doesItContains>
    <contains3>false</contains3>
  </doesItContains>
  <doesItContains>
     <contains3>false</contains3>
  </doesItContains>
  <doesItContains>
    <contains3>false</contains3>
  <contains3>false</contains3>
  </doesItContains>
  <doesItContains>
   <contains3>false</contains3>
   <contains3>true</contains3>
  </doesItContains>
  <doesItContains>
   <contains3>false</contains3>
 </doesItContains>
 </Orders>
```

I am unable to know why first code was not working.  could some one explain why first part code was not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your input payload has `<order>null</order>`. It doesn't have an `<items>` tag. You can see this by just showing the `$.*items`:

```
 %dw 1.0
 %output application/xml
 ---
 {
    Orders : payload.root.*order mapObject (
        test: $.*items 
 )}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Orders>
  <test>
    <items>155</items>
  </test>
  <test>
    <items>30</items>
  </test>
  <test>
    <items>15</items>
  </test>
  <test>
    <items>5</items>
  </test>
  <test>
    <items>4</items>
    <items>7</items>
  </test>
  <test>
    <items>1</items>
    <items>3</items>
  </test>
  <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</Orders>
```